# Why the different behavior on different approach

Tags: python, python-3.x, multithreading, pyqt, pyqt5

```
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *
from PyQt5.QtCore import *
from PyQt5.QtGui import *
import sys, time, threading


class Main_(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(Main_, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.resize(QSize(300, 250))
        self.show()
    
    def change_window_title(self, title):
        self.setWindowTitle(title)


def fctn(title_fctn):
    print('START')
    time.sleep(5)
    title_fctn('Test')
    print('DONE')



app = QApplication(sys.argv)
window = Main_()

# Method 1
fctn(window.change_window_title)

# Method 2
threading.Thread(
    target=lambda: window.change_window_title('test')
).start()

# Method 3
threading.Thread(
    target=lambda: fctn(window.change_window_title)
).start()

app.exec()
```

I want to change the title of the window. For that, I used 3 approaches:

- **Method 1:** Directly called the function
- **Method 2:** Directly called the function in a different thread
- **Method 3:** Called the function in a wrapper function, then called that wrapper function in a different thread.

**Note:** I don't know why I used `method 3`, but it was shocking why `method 2` and `method 3` ran differently. **Why?**

`Method 2` was freezing the app, while `Method 3` worked completely fine. **I thought both would give same results, but they didn't**. It would be a great help is someone would give proper explanation.

Comment: In linux with method 2 I don't see any freezing

Comment: @eyllanesc Did your code ran perfectly with method 2 (changed the title and no freeze)? Because I'm on windows, and only method 3 works

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Qt recommends that the GUI not be modified from a secondary thread and that is not because it cannot execute but that it does not guarantee its correct operation in all cases.

And what the OP points out is a sample of it since for example that code works in Linux with KDE as desktop manager but not in Windows.

Recommendation: Do not create or modify GUI elements directly from another thread.

Comment: How to modify gui element, if two threads needs to be ran continuously, (main gui thread and a function thread, and based on the function thread, needs to modify a gui element). For example: setting `setVisible(True/False)` based on some other thread.

Comment: @EctoRuseff then use signals. See this https://stackoverflow.com/a/66268548/6622587